# Howto show a certain recurring event in iCal with Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, icalendar

How can I show a certain recurring event in iCal with Applescript?

The code I use currently shows the first occurrence of that event, not the one I'm interested in.

```
tell application "iCal"
tell calendar CALENDAR_NAME
    set theEvent to first event whose uid = SOME_UID
end tell
if theEvent is not null then
    show theEvent
end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated.  Look at this samplescript from MacScripter.  It's a pretty impressive script.

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=29516

Comment: thanks for the link! Have you ever worked with the script? I get an error from the date function in that line: `return isotToDate(do shell script ("TZ=' " & TZ & " ' /bin/date -r " & eraTime & " +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"))`. But I guess the script won't make iCal to show the certain recurring event. My intention is to pop up the certain event in iCal...

Comment: No - I found that script some time ago and kept a copy, but I decided it just wasn't worth parsing the stuff in case Apple ever changed the format.